# Windows 8.1 + Classic Shell, how well does it restore Windows 7's functionality?

Tags: windows-7, shell, windows-8.1

I prefer a classic Windows UI. I enjoy Windows 7, but have heard that Windows 8.1, despite its unconventional interface, includes some under-the-hood improvements, such as faster boot times and better security.

I'm wondering which classic Windows UI elements [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) fails to fix or re-add in Windows 8.1.

Comment: Microsoft offers free Windows 8.1 virtual machines. Download it and install classic shell. We can't make this decision for you.  Try it and make the decision for yourself.

Comment: All Classic Shell features are listed on the website.  The best way to understand what differences will exist is to try my suggestion.

Comment: You should try unmodified Windows 8.1 first, maybe you will like that "unconventional" interface. If you won't be happy with it after some testing, you can apply Classic Shell and see if it suits your needs. All that can be done with a virtual machine as Ramhound suggested, this way your current OS will stay untouched. (By the way, I don't think that Win8 interface is unconventional. It's just different than what you're used to.)

Comment: Classic Shell is amazing, check it out if you're really adamant about not learning a new interface. If you're really against the modern apps, use powershell to uninstall all of them with one command.

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

<strike>No, it doesn't.</strike>

MDT Guy edited the question title, so I'll have to reword it: just *partially*. It can't restore everything that was either altered or removed.

## Longer answer

If you prefer a classic UI, you'll be disappointed: Windows 8.x will try to shove the Modern (previously known as "Metro") interface down your throat whenever possible.

Those articles are worth reading:

- [Features compromised in Windows 8](http://xpwasmyidea.blogspot.it/2011/09/features-removed-in-windows-8.html)
- [Pending fixes for Windows 8](http://xpwasmyidea.blogspot.it/2011/09/pending-fixes-for-windows-8.html)

The author goes to great lengths explaining the changes. Also, check this Wikipedia article out:

- [Features new to Windows 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_8)

While Windows 8.1 does bring [some improvements](http://lifehacker.com/all-the-new-stuff-in-windows-8-1-587098156), and Classic Shell has a [quite some nice features](http://www.classicshell.net/features/), some things just won't be fixed. Here are a few examples, in no particular order:

- Aero Glass transparency
- Desktop gadgets
- Flip 3D
- Autoplay
- File replace dialog
- Wireless network management
- Task Manager
- Open With dialog
- Windows update notifications

### Just try

As suggested, the best thing you can do is to actually try Windows 8.1, and see it for yourself. Microsoft has made available some [free virtual machines](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) for all their latest operating systems since Windows XP SP3. Eventually you could get the [90-day trial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh699156.aspx) ISO image, and install Windows 8.1 into a different partition. And if you don't want to mess with partitions, you can [install it in a Virtual Hard Disk](http://tipsandtricksforum.com/thread-113.html) (VHD).

### Official links

- [Virtual Machine (VM), Windows Virtual PC & Browserstack | Modern.IE](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads)
- [Download Windows 8.1 Enterprise Evaluation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh699156.aspx)

Comment: Aero Glass transparency, gadgets, task manager can be taken from Win7, there are third-party installers available on the internet. Open with dialog can be replaced by a third party program that emulates that of Win7.

Answer (score 3):

## Fact:

Yes, the under the hood improvements in windows 8 are significant. Security and Boot times are just the beginning, it's also markedly more stable and uses less power than previous releases. All versions of 8 both core and pro get bitlocker now. Features such as Hyper-V in the pro and enterprise versions allow you to run operating systems within windows without having to run third party software.

As far as functionality goes, classic shell does an amazing job restoring the Windows 7 style start menu if that's what you're ultimately emotionally attached to.

**MYTH:** The windows 8 interface is the worst thing since the plague.

**REALITY:** Windows 8.1 + Classic shell is quite good, it brings back the windows 7 start menu and a few other features removed in 8.

[image]

Classic shell does a pretty good job sitting on top of Win8.1 and makes the transition to 8.1 much easier. Half the whining about Windows 8 was over the lack of the start button which is now back in windows 8.1. You can even uninstall the "modern" apps if you really like.

Another feature to check out is the boot to desktop option added in 8.1, it solves a lot of your problems. Again, if you really are too stuck in the past to bother to learn a better way to do things, just uninstall the modern apps.

[image]

Comment: -1 for this antisocial comment: "All these Windows 8.1 cry babies should go back to Windows 98 if they're so obsessed with the past."

Comment: While kind of rough, it does sum up the real issue most people have with windows 8 and 8.1 - its a great OS, with a radically different UI. *Change is hard* - I admit the entire reason I use windows 8 with the stock UI was because of the contest on SU. I'd probably have been one of those 'you can take 7 out of my cold dead hands' guys. I'd rather throw Classic shell on a system than retrain my dad to use windows 8 though.

Comment: I've been working with IT for over twelve years, and I've never seen so much kicking and screaming over such a trvial issue. Yes, it was confusing when the start button was removed, but it's back now. I find it ironic that all the people who bemoaned the GUI changes in XP are now clinging to it for dear life, a stubborn and yet juvenile refusal to simply learn a better way to do something is the problem here, not the vendor. If these luddites had their way, we'd all be using Win98 still.

Comment: "All versions of 8 both core and pro get bitlocker now." Not quite: Windows 8.1 brings device encryption (a feature-limited BitLocker), but only if the underlying hardware supports secure boot, TPM 2.0, and connected standby. Also, users must log in with a Microsoft account. The traditional BitLocker is still available for non-Core editions only. Sources: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compare / http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306081.aspx / http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions#Comparison_chart / http://bit.ly/1bem54s / http://bit.ly/LxkxZS

Comment: Boot time is much greater on Win8 for me. What people usually speak of as "improved boot time" is that Win8 uses hybernation instead of shutdown by default (deceiving users).

Answer (score 1):

If you install [StartIsBack+](http://startisback.com/), [Aero Glass](http://glass8.berlios.de/) (with [Win7 like Theme](http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/027/1/6/aero7_v2_for_windows_8_8_1_by_damonkeyoncrack-d73nt4x.png)) and [OldNewExplorer](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-make-your-81-explorer-work-like-win78-one/) you can configure your Windows to bring back most UI parts of Windows 7 and reduce the ugly Win8 look a lot.

Now you have what Windows 8 should have been.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Classic Shell you would have to use a lot of other third party utilities, such as 7+ Taskbar Tweaker, Open With Enhanced, Old New Explorer, Shell Folder Fix, W8Classic, Folder Options X and a lot of other stuff. The Metro UI will still pop up occasionally, for instance, in Wi-Fi configuration and keyboard layout switcher. Yet it is possible to get rid of Metro UI in most cases.

This is how my user interface looks like:
[image]